# How to create a biaxial pie chart using chart.js in Node-RED

Tags: chart.js

As the title suggests, I would like to create a pie chart like an attachment using chart.js in Node-RED.
It's a pie chart showing the activity record of the day, but I'm worried because I can't set the two-axis label.

[image: Example of a biaxial pie chart I want to create]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) and define a `dataset` with `weight: 0` for displaying the numbers.

```
{
  data: [...Array(24)].map(v => 1),
  weight: 0,        
  rotation: -7.5,
  borderWidth: 20,
  datalabels: {
    formatter: (v, ctx) => ctx.dataIndex
  }
}
```

> For improving the positioning of the numbers, please consult the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` documentation [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html).

Please take a look at the runnable code below and see how it works.

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [...Array(24)].map(v => 1),
        weight: 0,        
        rotation: -7.5,
        borderWidth: 20,
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (v, ctx) => ctx.dataIndex
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: [48, 56, 33, 44],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)', 'rgba(124, 124, 124, 0.2)'],
        datalabels: {
          textAlign: 'center',
          formatter: (v, ctx) => {
            const dataset = ctx.chart.data.datasets[1];
            return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex] + ': ' + dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex];
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I will try it with reference to the source you taught me!

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted to do by referring to the source I was taught!
thank you very much!